# Google+ app listview layout with different views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-sliding

I'm trying to implement a sliding menu just like the one found in Google's Google+ Android app:

[image: GoogleApp]

I've got the actual sliding menu working but I'm having trouble implementing a scrolling view that can hold any type of child views.

For example I would like to have a header like the "NOTIFICATIONS" row in screenshot and below it a `ListView` with notification items. And I would like to have another sections below that list, perhaps called "ERRORS" and below it a different `ListView` with errors. And perhaps a `WebView` at the very bottom.

How is this best implemented?

**Note:** I have read [this tutorial](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296) but it's talking about a single `ListView`. I would like to construct this using a `LinearLayout` or alike, if that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up implementing this was with a `ScrollView` that I simply populated with `Views`.

There are some things to be considered when using a `ScrollView`, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573183/scrollview-optimizations) or the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

From what I understand, if you need a whole lot of items in a list then you should look at using a `ListView`. Otherwise a `ScrollView` will do just fine.